# print value of a dictionary when the dictionary is in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a little problem in my code and I would be happy if you can help me fix it.

My problem is to print value of a dictionary when the dictionary is in list.
I would love if you could help me fix this problem in my code.

```
def func0():

print "Quiz Program"
print "----------------------------------------------"
print "This program stores quiz questions and allows you to take the quiz"
print "----------------------------------------------"
size = input("Enter number of questions: ")
i = 0
for i in xrange(size):
    question = raw_input("Please enter a question, enter to exit: ")
    question_dictionary =  {"question" : question }
    count = input("How many possible answers  do you want this question to have: ")
    answer_list = []
    for j in xrange(count):
        answer = raw_input("Please enter the next answer: ")
        answer_list.append(answer)
    print "------------------------------------------------"
    for j in xrange(count):
        print j + 1,"." ,answer_list[j]
    print "------------------------------------------------"
    question_dictionary["answers"] = answer_list
    correct_answer = input("Please enter the value of the correct answer: ")
    question_dictionary["correct_answer"] = correct_answer
    new_list = []
    new_list.append(question_dictionary)
print "------------------------------------------------"
true_answer = 0
for i in xrange(size):
    print "question" ,i,".",  # problem to print the question
    print "------------------------------------------------"
    print "Possible Answers: "
    for j in xrange(count):
        print j + 1,"." ,answer_list[j]
    print "------------------------------------------------"
    user_answer = input("Please select an answer: ")
    if(user_answer == ): # problem to get the right answer
        print "well done, you answered the question correctly!"
        true_answer += 1
    else:
        print "sorry, you didn't get the correct answer."
    print "------------------------------------------------"
print "Your final score was", true_answer," out of", size

def main():

func0()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Thank you all

Comment: What is your code currently doing? What would you like it to do differently?

Comment: My code is a "Quiz Program" that keeps the FAQ then the user can play it. My problem  is print the question  and get the number of the correct answer. In the first comment I have to print the question that stored in list of dictionary and the other to get the right answer that stored in list of dictionary. @khelwood

Comment: First problem your question dicts aren't stored anywhere persistently. new_list = [] recreated in each iteration.

Comment: Did you try `print(new_list[0])`?  `pprint.pprint` will give prettier results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.This is just a fix only.Not actual pythonic.

```
print "Quiz Program"
print "----------------------------------------------"
print "This program stores quiz questions and allows you to take the quiz"
print "----------------------------------------------"
size = input("Enter number of questions: ")
i = 0
new_list = []
for i in xrange(size):
    question = raw_input("Please enter a question, enter to exit: ")
    question_dictionary =  {"question" : question }
    count = input("How many possible answers  do you want this question to have: ")
    answer_list = []
    for j in xrange(count):
        answer = raw_input("Please enter the next answer: ")
        answer_list.append(answer)
    print "------------------------------------------------"
    for j in xrange(count):
        print j + 1,"." ,answer_list[j]
    print "------------------------------------------------"
    question_dictionary["answers"] = answer_list
    correct_answer = input("Please enter the value of the correct answer: ")
    question_dictionary["correct_answer"] = correct_answer
    new_list.append(question_dictionary)
print "------------------------------------------------"
print new_list
true_answer = 0
for i in xrange(size):
    print "question" ,new_list[i]['question'],".\n",  # problem to print the question
    print "------------------------------------------------"
    print "Possible Answers: "
    for j in xrange(len(new_list[i]['answers'])):
        print j + 1,"." ,new_list[i]['answers'][j]
    print "------------------------------------------------"
    user_answer = input("Please select an answer: ")
    if(user_answer == new_list[i]['correct_answer']): # problem to get the right answer
        print "well done, you answered the question correctly!"
        true_answer += 1
    else:
        print "sorry, you didn't get the correct answer."
    print "------------------------------------------------"
print "Your final score was", true_answer," out of", size
```